What does average_depth in Snowflake actually mean?
I find the docs about the depth-related metrics in Snowflake to be somewhat lacking. Regarding average_depth, we can read the following:
Average overlap depth of each micro-partition in the table.

But what is overlap depth? The docs provide no definition of the term. Thankful for a clear and precide definition of what overlap depth and average_depth actually mean.

This page in the documentation shows a pretty good illustration:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions

Best way to think about these numbers, imo, is how many partitions (on average) is a specific value found?  You want that number to be as small as possible, so when you look for a value, Snowflake needs to read the fewest number of partitions.  An ideal clustered table would have a 1 overlap and average depth.
